# Julian day of the year in Java

Tags: java, julian-date

I have seen the "solution" at http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0506.html, but it doesn't work correctly.  E.g. yesterday (June 8) should have been 159, but it said it was 245.

So, does someone have a solution in Java for getting the current date's three digit Julian day (not Julian date - I need the day this year)?

Thanks! Mark

Comment: Hey Mark,
I also would like to know this, because I want to use it in an astronomie program i'm working on and I prefer to directly do that in java and not coding it myself :)

Comment: This day-of-year (1-366) more correctly known as [*Ordinal Date*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date). The use here of “Julian” is common but is, as far as I know, incorrect. Apparently a conflation with the [*Julian Day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) which is the integer assigned to a whole solar day in the Julian day count starting from noon Universal time, with Julian day number 0 assigned to the day starting at noon on January 1, 4713 BC, proleptic Julian calendar (November 24, 4714 BC, in the proleptic Gregorian calendar). Ex: 2000-01-01T12:00:00Z = 2,451,545.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all you want is the day-of-year, why don'you just use GregorianCalendars `DAY_OF_YEAR` field?

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
public class CalTest {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 8);
        gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, GregorianCalendar.JUNE);
        gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 2010);
        System.out.println(gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
}
```

}

Alternatively, you could calculate the difference between today's Julian date and that of Jan 1st of this year. But be sure to add 1 to the result, since Jan 1st is not the zeroth day of the year:

```
int[] now = {2010, 6, 8};
int[] janFirst = {2010, 1, 1};
double dayOfYear = toJulian(now) - toJulian(janFirst) + 1
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(dayOfYear).intValue());
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  That worked perfectly - I knew there had to be a simple answer.

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 11):

```
DateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("D");
System.out.println(d.format(date));
```

Answer (score 10):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now().getDayOfYear()
```

…or…

```
org.threeten.extra.DayOfYear.now()
```

## “Julian day” terminology

The term “Julian day” is sometimes used loosely to mean the [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) day of the year, or [*Ordinal date*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date), meaning a number from 1 to 365 or 366 ([leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)). January 1 is `1`, January 2 is `2`, December 31 is `365` (or `366` in leap years).

This loose (incorrect) use of `Julian` probably comes from the [use in astronomy](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php) and other fields of tracking dates as a continuous count of days since noon Universal Time on January 1, 4713 BCE (on the [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar)). Nowadays the Julian date is approaching two and half million, `2,457,576` today.

## java.time

The java.time framework built into Java 8 and later provides an easy facility to get the day-of-year.

The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. You can interrogate for the day-of-year.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of ( 2010 , Month.JUNE , 8 );
int dayOfYear = localDate.getDayOfYear ();
```

Dump to console. Results show that June 8, 2010 is indeed day # 159.

```
System.out.println ( "localDate: " + localDate + " | dayOfYear: " + dayOfYear );
```

> localDate: 2010-06-08 | dayOfYear: 159

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
int dayOfYear = today.getDayOfYear ();
```

Going the other direction, from a number to a date.

```
LocalDate ld = Year.of( 2017 ).atDay( 159 ) ;
```

## `org.threeten.extra.DayOfYear`

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library adds functionality to the *java.time* classes built into Java.

This library offers a class to represent explicitly the ordinal day of any year: [`DayOfYear`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/DayOfYear.html). Using this class rather than a mere integer number makes your code more self-documenting, provides type-safety, and ensures valid values.

```
DayOfYear dayOfYear = DayOfYear.from( LocalDate.of ( 2010 , Month.JUNE , 8 ) ) ;
```

Get a date for a `DayOfYear` with specific year.

```
LocalDate localDate = dayOfYear.atYear( 2023 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
// ...
final int julianDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Note that this doesn't take into account the "starts at noon" deal claimed by that weird site you referenced. That could be fixed by just checking the time of course.

Comment: On my system `System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getClass());` prints `class java.util.GregorianCalendar` but perhaps that's the same as julian.

Comment: The "Julian Date" or "Julian Day" has always meant to me the day of the year.  I think that's true for everybody except perhaps serious Classical scholars. If somebody is looking for the date as reckoned by a pre-Gregorian calendar, my solution won't work. Note that the question includes the sentence, "I need the day this year."

Comment: Before doing calculation do `setGregorianChange( new Date( Long.MAX_VALUE) )`.  Then it will be a `Julian` day.

Comment: I think you're all misunderstanding what "Julian Day" means in this context. It is *not* about historical calendars. The term "Julian Day" or "Julian Date" in modern data processing applications means simply the "day of year". Google it if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Pointy No, "Julian Date" spans several years. The Julian *day of the year* is not a standard term. And Orthodox Christians care what the date is by the Julian calendar, as they don't accept the authority of the Roman Pope Gregory.

Comment: Well "Mark", the user who posed the question, is missing in action, but seriously the Julian Day is something that became popular thirty or so years ago for storing dates in databases. That, in fact, was a big aspect of the "Y2K" problem: databases stored dates as 5-digit numbers, with 3 digits for the Julian day and 2 digits for the year. Old libraries had "toJulianDate" and "fromJulianDate" routines (of course punctuated stylistically for COBOL :-)  It is my suspicion that *that* is what the original question was about.

Comment: Note also that the original question says that 8 June 2010 should be "159", which is correct if "Julian Day" means simply, "day of year."

Comment: Yes, I meant Julian DAY of the year (three digits, like 159 for June 8, 2010).  There IS a Julian DATE, which is from some BC date and is a large number - that is NOT what I'm looking for.

Comment: sorry folks - been very busy
The answer is:
            Calendar today = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            int todayJulian = today.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

This gives the day of the year, aka Julian day (not date)

Answer (score 5):

I've read all the posts and something's not very clear I think.

user912567 mentionned Jean Meeus, and he's absolutely right

The most accurate definition I've found is given by Jean Meeus in its "Astronomical Algorithms" book (a must have, really...).

Julian Date is a **date**, expressed as usual, with a year, a month and a day.

Julian Day is a **number** (a real number), counted from year -4712 and is "...a continuous count of days..." (and fraction of day).
A **usefull** time scale used for accurate astronomical calculations.

Jean Meeus : "The Julian Day has nothing to do with the Julian calendar" ("Astronomical Algorithms", 2nd Edition, p.59)

Comment: Exactly so. It's worth noting that contrary to many answers and comments here the Julian day remains useful in modern computing, as you can calculate date *differences* with it in days with very little effort.

Answer (score 2):

if we get a double julian date such as chordiant decision manager

http://java.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/java-l/java-function-to-convert-julian-date-to-calendar-date-1947446

The following is working but second is not taken care of 
[How can I convert between a Java Date and Julian day number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655034/how-can-i-convert-between-a-java-date-and-julianday-number)

public static String julianDate(String julianDateStr) {

```
    try{
        // Calcul date calendrier Gr?gorien ? partir du jour Julien ?ph?m?ride 
        // Tous les calculs sont issus du livre de Jean MEEUS "Calcul astronomique" 
        // Chapitre 3 de la soci?t? astronomique de France 3 rue Beethoven 75016 Paris 
        // Tel 01 42 24 13 74 
        // Valable pour les ann?es n?gatives et positives mais pas pour les jours Juliens n?gatifs
        double jd=Double.parseDouble(julianDateStr);
          double z, f, a, b, c, d, e, m, aux;
            Date date = new Date();
            jd += 0.5;
            z = Math.floor(jd);
            f = jd - z;

            if (z >= 2299161.0) {
              a = Math.floor((z - 1867216.25) / 36524.25);
              a = z + 1 + a - Math.floor(a / 4);
            } else {
              a = z;
            }

            b = a + 1524;
            c = Math.floor((b - 122.1) / 365.25);
            d = Math.floor(365.25 * c);
            e = Math.floor((b - d) / 30.6001);
            aux = b - d - Math.floor(30.6001 * e) + f;
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (int) aux);

            double hhd= aux-calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);                
            aux = ((aux - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) * 24);




            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) aux);

            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) ((aux - calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) * 60));



         // Calcul secondes 
            double mnd = (24 * hhd) - calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            double ssd = (60 * mnd) - calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 
            int ss = (int)(60 * ssd);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,ss);



            if (e < 13.5) {
              m = e - 1;
            } else {
              m = e - 13;
            }
            // Se le resta uno al mes por el manejo de JAVA, donde los meses empiezan en 0.
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (int) m - 1);
            if (m > 2.5) {
              calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, (int) (c - 4716));
            } else {
              calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, (int) (c - 4715));
            }


        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        //System.out.println("Appnumber= "+appNumber+" TimeStamp="+timeStamp+" Julian Date="+julianDateStr+" Converted Date="+sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
        return sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for Julian Day as in the [day count since 4713 BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), then you can use the following code instead:

```
private static int daysSince1900(Date date) {
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTime(date);

    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (year < 1900 || year > 2099) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("daysSince1900 - Date must be between 1900 and 2099");
    }
    year -= 1900;
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int days = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    if (month < 3) {
        month += 12;
        year--;
    }
    int yearDays = (int) (year * 365.25);
    int monthDays = (int) ((month + 1) * 30.61);

    return (yearDays + monthDays + days - 63);
}

/**
 * Get day count since Monday, January 1, 4713 BC
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day
 * @param date
 * @param time_of_day percentage past midnight, i.e. noon is 0.5
 * @param timezone in hours, i.e. IST (+05:30) is 5.5
 * @return
 */
private static double julianDay(Date date, double time_of_day, double timezone) {
    return daysSince1900(date) + 2415018.5 + time_of_day - timezone / 24;
}
```

The above code is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/9593736, and so is limited to dates between 1900 and 2099.

Comment: for monthDays  ´(month + 1) * 153/5´ works with integers only. Sad that after 2 decades of Java Run Time Design, you have to get back to elementaries, that you used before Java.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Basil Bourque answer, below is my implementation to get the Julian day of the year using system default Zone ID.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
int julianDay = localDate.getDayOfYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really just need "day of the year", indeed, this is just Gregorian/standard calendar and the answer of [wallenborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3005757/11023821) is correct.

However, if you care for the actual Jualian-Day or any further astronomically-relevant information, I wrote a small utility for this

https://github.com/wirklich-xyz/wirklich.xyz.astro/blob/main/astro-time/src/main/java/xyz/wirklich/astro/time/JulianDay.java

which is also published on maven central at [xyz.wirklich.astro](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xyz/wirklich/astro/)

Feel free to use it. This is very precise for all reasonable use cases.

Answer (score -1):

You can also get the "Julian Date" or "Ordinal Date" this way:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    LocalDate myObj = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println(myObj);
    System.out.println("Julian Date:" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

  }
}
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since the accepted answer contains that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.