# How can I convert between a Java Date and Julian day number?

Tags: java, date, julian-date

How can a Java `Date` be converted into a `double` that represents a Julian day?
How can a Julian day number be converted into a Java `Date`?

---

```
public static double dateToJulian(Date date) {

    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    int year;
    int month;
    float day;
    int a;
    int b;
    double d;
    double frac;

    frac = (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) / 0.000024 + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 0.001440);

    b = 0;

    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

    DecimalFormat ceroPlaces = new DecimalFormat("0");
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    day = Float.parseFloat(ceroPlaces.format(day) + "." + ceroPlaces.format(Math.round(frac)));

    if (month < 3) {
        year--;
        month += 12;
    }

    if (FuncionSoporte.compararFechas(calendar.getTime(), calendar.getGregorianChange()) > 0) {
        a = year / 100;
        b = 2 - a + a / 4;
    }

    d = Math.floor(365.25 * year) + Math.floor(30.6001 * (month + 1)) + day + 1720994.5 + b;

    return (d); 
}
```

---

```
public static Date julianToDate(double jd) {

    double z, f, a, b, c, d, e, m, aux;
    Date date = new Date();
    jd += 0.5;
    z = Math.floor(jd);
    f = jd - z;

    if (z >= 2299161.0) {
      a = Math.floor((z - 1867216.25) / 36524.25);
      a = z + 1 + a - Math.floor(a / 4);
    } else {
      a = z;
    }

    b = a + 1524;
    c = Math.floor((b - 122.1) / 365.25);
    d = Math.floor(365.25 * c);
    e = Math.floor((b - d) / 30.6001);
    aux = b - d - Math.floor(30.6001 * e) + f;

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (int) aux);
    aux = ((aux - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) * 24);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) aux);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) ((aux - calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) * 60));

    if (e < 13.5) {
      m = e - 1;
    } else {
      m = e - 13;
    }
    // Se le resta uno al mes por el manejo de JAVA, donde los meses empiezan en 0.
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (int) m - 1);
    if (m > 2.5) {
      calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, (int) (c - 4716));
    } else {
      calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, (int) (c - 4715));
    }
    return calendar.getTime();
  }
```

EDIT: Added FuncionSoporte.java code.

```
public class FuncionSoporte {

    /**
     * Compare 2 dates. If the first is after the second result will be positive, if the second is after then negative, 0 if they are equal.
     */
    public static int compararFechas(Date d1, Date d2) {

        Calendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();
        c1.setTime(d1);
        Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
        c2.setTime(d2);

        if (c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            if (c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == c2.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
                return c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            } else {
                return c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) - c2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            }
        } else {
            return c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - c2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should take those code snippets and post them as answers instead of in the question itself. That way users can vote on them appropriately.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651440/how-can-i-convert-between-a-java-date-and-julianday-number-dates)

Comment: A moderator closed your post. Why would you think it was appropriate to just repost it?

Comment: Well, I am new to the StackOverflow and the reason the moderator closed my post was because question was not clear, so I (as per suggestion in previous post) reposted it as a question and in the body the answer, but seems I was also mistaken and I should have first posted the question and later answer it myself (but still the system does not allow new users to answer their own questions in less thn 24 hours).

Comment: @will824 - If you do that (make your question *only* a question, and answer it after 24 hours), this is less likely to get closed.

Comment: [Pretend you're on Jeopardy!](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Cool, I will take that on mind from now onwards.

Comment: The question that this was closed as a duplicate of has been deleted. Perhaps it should be reopened and edited the way @RobHruska suggested...?

Comment: Closing a question as a duplicate of it's deleted copy is very odd indeed.

Comment: I've re-opened this, please can you move the solution to a self-answer, otherwise it'll be closed by the community as Not a Real Question. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev can you give instructions on how to move this question to Self Answer?.

Comment: Just click on the "Answer you question" button below.

Comment: Your code uses a package called "FuncionSoporte". Could you please provide it too?

Comment: @Josep I added the missing code. Sorry for the delay I hope it helps.

Comment: The first two sentences certainly are a valid and interesting Question. I could provide an Answer showing use of the `JulianFields` class built into Java 8 (and more). Instead I will post my Answer on this [later duplicate Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14988459/642706).