# How to Validate Ordinal Dates?

Tags: java, spring, date

My julian date is in 7 digit format YYYYDDD.
I want to make sure all the scenarios of leap years should be covered. Currently I have put a check on days. Is there any utility validating it ?

Comment: @BasilBourque to be fair those answers make no mention of how to *validate* a date.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Point taken. I reopened the Question. Thank you for pointing out my error. I’ll provide an Answer here too.

Comment: Julian dates are obsoletes. Just check that last 2 digits of YY are multiple of 4. But it is centuries (on most of world) that we passed to Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi This question is asking about [*ordinal dates*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date), not the [*Julian calendar*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar). “Julian date” is a common misnomer for “ordinal date”. The misnomer likely comes from a misunderstanding of [*Julian day*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) counting used in astronomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make sure all the scenarios of leap years should be covered.
> Currently I have put a check on days. Is there any utility validating
> it ?

Yes, simply format the strings to `LocalDate` using the pattern, `uuuuDDD` and the leap years will be automatically be taken into consideration by the parsing API.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The 100th day of the year, 2020
        String strDate1 = "2020100";

        // The 100th day of the year, 2019
        String strDate2 = "2019100";

        // Notice 'D' (day-of-year) instead of 'd' (day-of-month)
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuDDD");

        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(strDate1, dtf);
        LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse(strDate2, dtf);

        System.out.println(date1);
        System.out.println(date2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-04-09
2019-04-10
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ordinal date

“Julian” is a misnomer for a date represented as a year with day-of-year number. [*Ordinal date*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date) is a better name.

The misnomer causes confusion as an ordinal date has nothing to do with the [*Julian calendar*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar). The misnomer likely comes from a misunderstanding of [*Julian day*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) counting used in astronomy.

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with a custom format. In your custom formatting pattern, use triple uppercase-D,  `DDD`, for day-of-year number.

Attempt to parse your string input. Trap for `DateTimeParseException`.

```java
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuDDD" ) ;
try
{
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;
} 
catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
{
    // handle faulty input
}
```

### ISO 8601

I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The standard format for an ordinal date is 8 characters, using a hyphen between the year and the day-of-year number. The `DateTimeFormatter` class defines that format as a constant: [`ISO_ORDINAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ORDINAL_DATE). I recommend strongly that you stick to the ISO 8601 formats when exchanging date-time values as text.

For more explanation, see [my detailed Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38256382/642706) on similar Question.